# How do you use PowerShell to extract Epub meta data (XML)?

Tags: xml, powershell, epub

I'm not new to PowerShell, but I am to XML parsing.  Basically I want to extract the title, creator, and publisher information from the OPF file, which is just an xml file.  The book below is Moby Dick from Google's epub v3 sample collection.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" version="3.0" xml:lang="en" unique-identifier="pub-  id" prefix="cc: http://creativecommons.org/ns#">
    <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
        <dc:title id="title">Moby-Dick</dc:title>
        <meta refines="#title" property="title-type">main</meta>
        <dc:creator id="creator">Herman Melville</dc:creator>
        <meta refines="#creator" property="file-as">MELVILLE, HERMAN</meta>
        <meta refines="#creator" property="role" scheme="marc:relators">aut</meta>
        <dc:identifier id="pub-id">code.google.com.epub-samples.moby-dick-basic</dc:identifier>
        <dc:language>en-US</dc:language>
        <meta property="dcterms:modified">2012-01-18T12:47:00Z</meta>
        <dc:publisher>Harper &amp; Brothers, Publishers</dc:publisher>
        <dc:contributor id="contrib1">Dave Cramer</dc:contributor>
        <meta refines="#contrib1" property="role" scheme="marc:relators">mrk</meta>
        <dc:rights>This work is shared with the public using the Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported (CC BY-SA 3.0) license.</dc:rights>        
        <link rel="cc:license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/"/>
        <meta property="cc:attributionURL">http://code.google.com/p/epub-samples/</meta>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

I've tried:

```
[xml]$opf = gc path/to/package.opf
$opf.package.metdata
```

I'm only able to get the tag and attribute information with this and not the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the #text property like this to get some of the values:

```
[xml] $opf = gc .\moby.opf

$title = $opf.package.metadata.title.'#text'
$creator = $opf.package.metadata.creator.'#text'
$publisher = $opf.package.metadata.publisher

Write-Host "$title written by $creator and published by $publisher"
```

Comment: ahhhh so that's how it works.  Do you have any articles I can reference for this information?  I'd like to know more about how that works.

Comment: Also how do you get the text of the <Meta> tags, i.e. <meta refines="#creator" property="file-as">MELVILLE, HERMAN</meta>?

Comment: Nevermind, I guess I can do it like this $opf.package.metadata.meta | %{$_.'#text'}.  Thanks for your help Magnus.