# need to extract set of 4 digit numbers from epub or text file in Batch

Tags: regex, powershell, ubuntu

I have hundreds of epub files. I need to extract dates from text (only years like 1947, 1987 etc) with file names
i mean, output should be like,this filename contains this this dates and so on
for example epub01 contains 1995 1945 1986.
            epub02 contains 1926 1946 1948.
if anyone can provide me a PowerShell script or script that can run in ubuntu terminal, that would be great.

Although I have epub files but I can extract to text file myself. if you have script for text files.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's not a code writing service, you should try yourself at first. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: [How do you use PowerShell to extract Epub meta data (XML)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13649751) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only provide a script for text files. You can read them using the `Get-Content` cmdlet and use a `regex` to grab your values containg a negative lookahead and negative lookbehind to ensure there are exactly four digits:

```
$content = Get-Content 'your_file' -Raw
$matches = [regex]::Matches($content, '(?<!\d)(\d{4})(?!\d)')
$matches | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Groups[1].Value
}
```

---

**Regex explanation:**

```
(?<!\d)(\d{4})(?!\d)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks for the script Martin. i used this script in powershell. but nothing happens. so i used another script in power shell                     $input_path = ‘C:\Users\Falcon\Desktop\tn2\Before you read.docx’
$output_file = ‘C:\Users\Falcon\Desktop\tn2\extracted_ip_addresses.txt’
$regex = ‘\b\d{1,4}\b’
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file                                         but it gives me some random numbers . could modify it to my need

Comment: Well, you a docx document which contains markup code so its not suitable to read it with Get-Content and parse it with regex. I thought you have a text file.... However, my regex could be simplified using `\b`...

Comment: look martin i am novice. i converted doc to text. if you could give step by step tutorial. the i will be able to do it.

Comment: I provided you a piece of code to grab all 4 digit numbers from a text file which you requested. All you have to do is to replace your_file with a text file (not epub nor docx).

Comment: i did that. but nothings happens. powershell dosent show any error. look                                                                                                    $content = Get-Content 'C:\Users\Falcon\Desktop\tn2\Before you read2.txt' -Raw
$matches = [regex]::Matches($content, '(?<!\d)(\d{4})(?!\d)')
$matches | ForEach-Object {C:\Users\Falcon\Desktop\tn2
    $_.Groups[1].Value
}

Comment: Now its working. many thanks. but i have thousnads of text files with different name. could it sort the date according to filename. need batch extraction.

Comment: Yes, you can. But please start another question or try to solve this for yourself. Also consider to accept the answer.

Comment: only one more thing. i modified your string to this                                $input_path = ‘C:\Users\Falcon\Desktop\tn2\Before you read2.txt’
$output_file = ‘C:\Users\Falcon\Desktop\tn2\extracted_ip_addresses.txt’
$matches = [regex]::Matches($content, '(?<!\d)(\d{4})(?!\d)')
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file                                                it giving me output file. but still need batch script. i  have a folder that contains thousand text file.

Comment: Take a look at the `Get-ChildItem cmdlet` and pipe the result to the Foreach-Object cmdlet...